# How to conditionally count based on grouping and time constraints

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am counting the number of cases of lameness in cattle.  I want to determine the number of cases in the current lactation and over the animals lifetime.

The following sample data is provided as an example.

```
[[52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-03-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-03-04 00:00:00'),
  106,
  1,
  1],
 [52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-03-04 00:00:00'),
  106,
  1,
  1],
 [52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00'),
  307,
  2,
  2],
 [52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-03-04 00:00:00'),
  106,
  1,
  2],
 [52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00'),
  307,
  2,
  3],
 [52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-03-04 00:00:00'),
  106,
  1,
  2],
 [52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-05 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00'),
  307,
  2,
  3],
 [52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-06 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-03-04 00:00:00'),
  106,
  1,
  2],
 [52316,
  Timestamp('2021-11-18 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-10-06 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2022-09-21 00:00:00'),
  307,
  2,
  3],
 [35724,
  Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-09-08 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-08-26 00:00:00'),
  4,
  1,
  1],
 [35724,
  Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-09-08 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-09-08 00:00:00'),
  17,
  2,
  2],
 [35724,
  Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-11-13 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-08-26 00:00:00'),
  4,
  1,
  2],
 [35724,
  Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-11-13 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-09-08 00:00:00'),
  17,
  2,
  3],
 [35724,
  Timestamp('2018-08-22 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-11-13 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2018-10-05 00:00:00'),
  44,
  3,
  4],
 [10295,
  Timestamp('2005-01-19 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2006-03-07 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2006-03-03 00:00:00'),
  408,
  1,
  1],
 [10295,
  Timestamp('2008-04-30 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2009-01-08 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2008-06-12 00:00:00'),
  43,
  1,
  2],
 [10295,
  Timestamp('2008-04-30 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2009-01-08 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2008-08-28 00:00:00'),
  120,
  2,
  3],
 [10295,
  Timestamp('2008-04-30 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2009-01-08 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2008-12-01 00:00:00'),
  215,
  3,
  4],
 [10295,
  Timestamp('2008-04-30 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2009-04-09 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2008-06-12 00:00:00'),
  43,
  1,
  2],
 [10295,
  Timestamp('2008-04-30 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2009-04-09 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2008-08-28 00:00:00'),
  120,
  2,
  3],
 [10295,
  Timestamp('2008-04-30 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2009-04-09 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2008-12-01 00:00:00'),
  215,
  3,
  4],
 [10295,
  Timestamp('2008-04-30 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2009-04-09 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2009-02-09 00:00:00'),
  285,
  4,
  5]]
```

This produces the following dataframe

```
    NID      Fdat        RxDate     LameDate    DIM Lact_xLame  Life_xLame
0   52316   2021-11-18  2022-03-04  2022-03-04  106    1           1
1   52316   2021-11-18  2022-09-21  2022-03-04  106    1           1
2   52316   2021-11-18  2022-09-21  2022-09-21  307    2           2
3   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-04  2022-03-04  106    1           2
4   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-04  2022-09-21  307    2           3
5   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-05  2022-03-04  106    1           2
6   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-05  2022-09-21  307    2           3
7   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-06  2022-03-04  106    1           2
8   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-06  2022-09-21  307    2           3
9   35724   2018-08-22  2018-09-08  2018-08-26  4      1           1
10  35724   2018-08-22  2018-09-08  2018-09-08  17     2           2
11  35724   2018-08-22  2018-11-13  2018-08-26  4      1           2
12  35724   2018-08-22  2018-11-13  2018-09-08  17     2           3
13  35724   2018-08-22  2018-11-13  2018-10-05  44     3           4
14  10295   2005-01-19  2006-03-07  2006-03-03  408    1           1
15  10295   2008-04-30  2009-01-08  2008-06-12  43     1           2
16  10295   2008-04-30  2009-01-08  2008-08-28  120    2           3
17  10295   2008-04-30  2009-01-08  2008-12-01  215    3           4
18  10295   2008-04-30  2009-04-09  2008-06-12  43     1           2
19  10295   2008-04-30  2009-04-09  2008-08-28  120    2           3
20  10295   2008-04-30  2009-04-09  2008-12-01  215    3           4
21  10295   2008-04-30  2009-04-09  2009-02-09  285    4           5
```

I have prepared the following code to count the number of `Lact_xLame` (cases of lameness that are more than 7 days apart within the lactation that preceed the `RxDate` (Time of a mastitis event) and `Life_xLame` that counts the cumulative number of cases (cases of lameness that are more than 7 days apart) of lameness over the life of the animal that also preced the `RxDate` (time of mastitis event)

```
df['Lact_xLame'] = (df.groupby(['NID', 'RxDate', 'Fdat'])
                    ['DIM'].diff().abs().gt(7)
                    .groupby([df['RxDate'], df['Fdat']])
                    .cumsum()+1
                 )

df['Life_xLame'] = (df.groupby(['NID'])
                    ['DIM'].diff().abs().gt(7)
                    .groupby([df['RxDate'], df['NID']])
                    .cumsum()+1
                 )

df
```

The `Lact_xLame` is calculating correctly.  The output of `Life_xLame` is unexpected.

The output that I am looking for is

```
    NID      Fdat        RxDate     LameDate    DIM Lact_xLame  Life_xLame
0   52316   2021-11-18  2022-03-04  2022-03-04  106    1           1
1   52316   2021-11-18  2022-09-21  2022-03-04  106    1           1
2   52316   2021-11-18  2022-09-21  2022-09-21  307    2           2
3   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-04  2022-03-04  106    1           1
4   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-04  2022-09-21  307    2           2
5   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-05  2022-03-04  106    1           1
6   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-05  2022-09-21  307    2           2
7   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-06  2022-03-04  106    1           1
8   52316   2021-11-18  2022-10-06  2022-09-21  307    2           2
9   35724   2018-08-22  2018-09-08  2018-08-26  4      1           1
10  35724   2018-08-22  2018-09-08  2018-09-08  17     2           2
11  35724   2018-08-22  2018-11-13  2018-08-26  4      1           1
12  35724   2018-08-22  2018-11-13  2018-09-08  17     2           2
13  35724   2018-08-22  2018-11-13  2018-10-05  44     3           3
14  10295   2005-01-19  2006-03-07  2006-03-03  408    1           1
15  **10295 2008-04-30**    2009-01-08  2008-06-12  43     1           2
16  10295   2008-04-30  2009-01-08  2008-08-28  120    2           3
17  10295   2008-04-30  2009-01-08  2008-12-01  215    3           4
18  10295   2008-04-30  2009-04-09  2008-06-12  43     1           2
19  10295   2008-04-30  2009-04-09  2008-08-28  120    2           3
20  10295   2008-04-30  2009-04-09  2008-12-01  215    3           4
21  10295   2008-04-30  2009-04-09  2009-02-09  285    4           5
```

For `Life_xLame` I am looking for a cumulative count that includes cases from a previous lactation `Fdat` as illustrated by `NID = 10295`.   The output for `NID == 10295` is correct.  For the other NID examples it is not resetting back to 1 for the first case of lameness preceding `RxDate` (Time of mastitis event.  These other NID numbers did not have a case of lameness in the preceding lactation (ie there is only one `Fdat` for 35725 and 52316).

My understanding is that the `df.groupby(['NID']` statement focuses attention on rows with the same NID. The `['DIM'].diff().abs().gt(7)` statement checks to make sure that the difference in DIM between rows is greater than 7. The `.groupby([df['RxDate']`, `df['NID']]).cumsum()+1` statement groups the records by RxDate and NID and counts them returning the count number as `['Life_xLame']`.  What confuses me is that when it is going to the next `RxDate` it is starting the count at 2 rather than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally** figured it out!!

The problem was associated with the way the data was sorted relative to how the groupby statements were set up.  Needed to include DIM in the sort.

```
df = df.sort_values(['NID', 'Fdat', 'DIM'])


df['Lact_xLame'] = (df.groupby(['NID', 'Fdat', 'RxDate'])
                    ['DIM'].diff().abs().gt(7)
                    .groupby([df['NID'], df['Fdat'], df['RxDate']])
                    .cumsum()+1
                 )

df['Life_xLame'] = (df.groupby(['NID'])
                    ['DIM'].diff().abs().gt(7)
                    .groupby([df['NID']])
                    .cumsum()+1
                 )

df
```

Produced the output I was looking for.